# How do I add file permissions with the command line in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003

I've tried using xcacls and cacls on a Windows Server 2003 computer but they all *replace* the existing permissions when I use /g. Does anyone know of a command-line tool that will simply **add** permissions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you use /G *and* **/E** (edit mode) together (and most likely /T as well).

For reference, here is the complete usage information from the command `CACLS /?`

> ```
> CACLS filename [/T] [/E] [/C] [/G user:perm] [/R user [...]]
>                [/P user:perm [...]] [/D user [...]]
>    filename      Displays ACLs.
>    /T            Changes ACLs of specified files in
>                  the current directory and all subdirectories.
>    /E            Edit ACL instead of replacing it.
>    /C            Continue on access denied errors.
>    /G user:perm  Grant specified user access rights.
>                  Perm can be: R  Read
>                               W  Write
>                               C  Change (write)
>                               F  Full control
>    /R user       Revoke specified user's access rights (only valid with /E).
>    /P user:perm  Replace specified user's access rights.
>                  Perm can be: N  None
>                               R  Read
>                               W  Write
>                               C  Change (write)
>                               F  Full control
>    /D user       Deny specified user access.
> Wildcards can be used to specify more that one file in a command.
> You can specify more than one user in a command.
>
> Abbreviations:
>    CI - Container Inherit.
>         The ACE will be inherited by directories.
>    OI - Object Inherit.
>         The ACE will be inherited by files.
>    IO - Inherit Only.
>         The ACE does not apply to the current file/directory.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use a tool from helgeklein.com, called SetACL.exe. Very powerful tool, try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at CACLS, don't forget to take a look at ICACLS